# Actual minimum size for JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

When you make a `JFrame` without setting a minimum size, you cannot make it smaller than a certain size, leaving the minimize/exit button visible. Is it possible to get the limit?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#getMinimumSize() ?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#getInsets() this may be relevant too. Try playing around with some of these values